# how to use regex in switch case in expect script?

Tags: regex, tcl, expect

Normally, switch case in *expect* looks like this:

```
switch -- $count \
1 {
set type byte
} 2 {
set type word
} big {
set type array
} default {
puts "$count is not a valid type"
}
```

I need to use regex operators such as | or & - how can I do that?

The below example does not work with *expect* code :

```
switch -- $variable \
("a"|"b"|"c") {
              do something
}
```

**("a"|"b"|"c")**  represents a or b or c, but it does not seem to work.

How do I use such statements in switch or may be an and statement?

Comment: are you using only expect, or expect with bash, for instance?

Comment: i am doing everything using expect but i am using bash for parsing the input file for my script. the the switch case part is from expect code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-regexp` option for the command, and brace the expression the Tcl way. Also, you can use braces around all the switches so you don't have to use line continuations.

```
switch -regexp -- $variable {
    {a|b|c} {
        do something
    }
    {^[def].*(?:g|h|i)} {
        do a different thing
    }
    default {
        do something else
    }
}
```

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/switch.htm
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: An Expect tip: while developing your program, use `exp_internal 1` near the top of the script.